# Is It Accepted Or Legal To Do this

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a method in a class say

```
// super class
public class Car{

    public void printMe(Car c){
          if(c instanceof BMW){
            Utility.printString("Bmw");
      }else if(em instanceof VOLVO){
            Utility.printString("Volvo");
      }else if(em instanceof AUDI){
            Utility.printString("Audi");
      }else {
            Utility.printString("Kia");
        }
    }

// sub classes 

public class Bmw extends Car{

}

public class Volvo extends Car{
}

public class Audi extends Car{
}

public class Kia extends Car{
}

}
```

Now here i have a different class that loops through a list of Cars and print the correct statement according to the type of the Car

```
public class AccessCars{
   ArrayLists<Car> carsList = listOfcars();

for(Car car: carsList){
   car.PrintMe(car);   
}

}
```

In the loop above i call the printMe(Car c) method on car en give car as an argument. Is is legal to do that? And if not, what is the best way of doing it?

thanks for your answer

Comment: It is highly illegal, and if the coding police catch you doing it, you'll serve hard time in the federal penn.  Thankfully it's easy enough to break out with a fork bomb.

Comment: First of all the code is bad style and second: Why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a better way will be:

```
public abstract  class Car {
public abstract void printMe();
}
public class Audi {
@Override
public void printMe() {
Utility.printString("Audi");
}
```

this is the OOP way to do it - using polymorphism

 note that Car is implicit argument for printMe()

Comment: I think you mean implicit, not explicit.

Comment: Actually Car is an IMPLICIT argument.  An explicit argument is one that you pass inside the round brackets.

Comment: @Laurence thanks for the comment - I did mean implicit... fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise against polymorphism in this case -- every class prints out a string in the same way. The behavior is constant -- only the value printed varies. As such, the correct approach (IMO) is a variable that's printed out by `printMe`, and each derived class just initializes the variable appropriately.

Comment: yes -- have a constructor argument on `Car` which is the name.

Comment: Given the example as presented. Car should have a "String brand;" field. No subclassing necessary at all.

Comment: @Daniel T: If that's all there is to the class, you're right. I was assuming (perhaps incorrectly) that there would/might be something else included that would justify subclassing, even though this doesn't.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Even if there is more to the class, this particular bit should still be a field on the Car class. Subclassing is best used for changing behavior. What is being discussed here is simply data.

Comment: @Daniel T: Yes, that's pretty much what I said in the first place (or at least intended to say, anyway).

Answer (score 2):

It's legal, but not very good design. Perhaps a better approach is to define an abstract method `Car.getModel()` and implement it in each subclass to return the appropriate value. After all, you don't want to have to change the code for `Car` every time you add a new subclass.

Answer (score 2):

Um, you can do that ... but I think you're missing the point of inheritance and overriding methods:

```
public class Car{

    void printMe()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm a Car!");
    }
}

public class Audi extends Car{

    void printMe()
    {
        System.out.println("I'm an Audi!");
    }
}

for(Car car: carsList){
    car.PrintMe()
}
```

You get the overriden methods. Each car will print its name.

That being said, this is a silly example just to show how that works.

You'd really declare the `Car` class `abstract` and have `printMe()` be abstract, unless you had some reason to ever instantiate `Car` directly.

Comment: Jerry Coffin's answer was much better. Inheritance isn't even called for in the example presented by the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

It's generally not acceptable to do this; since you already have "specialized" classes, why not put the `printMe` method in these classes? In case you want to enforce the subclasses have their own version of `printMe`, just make the `printMe` method in the super-class as abstract.

On a side note, another thing you might be interested would be a [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

> In object-oriented programming and
>   software engineering, the visitor
>   design pattern is a way of separating
>   an algorithm from an object structure
>   it operates on. A practical result of
>   this separation is the ability to add
>   new operations to existing object
>   structures without modifying those
>   structures. It is one way to easily
>   follow the open/closed principle.

Comment: if he doesn't "get" polymorphism yet, the Visitor pattern will be way beyond him.  Besides, simple polymorphism is a much better solution for what he's trying to do ...

Comment: @Stephen: Agreed, I think I was going too fast for the OP; I mentioned Visitor pattern so that the OP would know that polymorphism is not the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Definetly not OK, to do it.

I would define an abstract method called .Print() on the super class in such a way every subclass of Car must override it, and have your own way of Printing. Just like many samples above!

Answer (score 0):

It is legal, however, not best of practice.
instanceof is a heavy operation on runtime environment and as such should be avoided if possible. This is not needed here, as every Car instance do the same thing - print itself. Consider this example:

```
public class Car {
  // do some great stuff here...

    public abstract String printMe();
}

public class Audi extends Car {
  // do some great stuff here...

  public String printMe() {
    return "Audi rocks!";
  }
}
// same for the other car models...
```

now iterate on the Car collection and run printMe for each.

Comment: A class containing `abstract` methods must also be declared `abstract` ;) I'm afraid you can't do great stuff there.